# wsdl2objc authenticationProperties does not exist

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to call my web service using wsdl2objc. I found the following code/document, but it seemed that the binding object (generated by wsdl2objc) has no such property named authenticationProperties.

```
   NSDictionary *authProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:credentials 
                                                               forKey:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

   binding.authenticationProperties = authProperties;
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on wsdl2objc 0.7. Have you by any chance tried Tom Fobear's suggestion below on building the code off the source control? Would save me sometime if you can help confirm if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a part of a version that is not out yet. That is the best answer I have found so far. I suppose you could download the code off their subversion, build it, and generate your classes with the latest. Hope they update it soon.